# setVolumeControlStream() not working

Tags: android, button, stream, controls, volume

I'm calling `setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);` in the `onCreate()` methods of every of my three Activities in the application, but none of them is working. In fact, when I'm pressing the volume control buttons - nothing happens at all. Here's a quote from the documentation:

> It is not guaranteed that the hardware volume controls will always change this stream's volume (for example, if a call is in progress, its stream's volume may be changed instead).

All that my application is doing is playing music in the background and playing some sounds. Why should it not work? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What API are you writing the app for? I am curious because I am having similar trouble with API 7 (Android 2.1) but have no problem with that single line of code with API 8 (Android 2.2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have overriden onKeyDown() etc make sure that you do call super.onKeyDown() as well for keys that you do not handle or at least for the volume up/down keys, e.g. in your view subclass:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
   // do your stuff here...
   if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) || (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN)) {
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }   
    return true;
}
```